# ie7 bug - divs sliding off the screen in certain wordpress pages

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer-7

I've got a weird ie7 bug on 2 pages on a wordpress site I'm working on.

Certain divs seem to slide to weird positions, on one of them it's completely of the screen:
http://danabick-shanuni.co.il/?page_id=46
and the other:
http://danabick-shanuni.co.il/?cat=5

Also, might be related and my be not, the content of the "created by" link in the footer is mixed up as well.

I was trying to see where the problem is coming from, and gave the problematic pieces a red border just in ie7, and what's really weird is that the border is actually in the right place, but the content isn't inside the bordered area.
Any ideas what could be causing this?..

Thnx in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, someone found the answer to the problem for me:
apparently, some of the wordpress css adds "position:relative;" to the article there.

Removed that - problem solved...
:)

Answer (score 1):

The new html5 tags (e.g. `article`) are unknown in IE7. Try adding following in the html `head`:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

=== UPDATE ===

The `dir="rtl"` attribute of the html-tag makes problems in IE7, can you remove it?